# I iterate over an array with map and then try to change a boolen of an object from false to true with an onClick. UI doesn't reflect it but log does

Tags: javascript, reactjs

CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-taussig-n7e7q3?file=/src/App.js

As you can see, I iterate over the `flaggers` array with `.map` and render `<div>true</div>` or `<div onClick={() => setToTrue(flag)}>false</div>`. I assumed that if I were to click the second div, the refer property of that flag would be set to true and the component would re-render, making the div change to `<div>true</div>` but that doesn't seem to be the case.

In the setToTrue function I console.log the post object, and I can see that the refer property of the second flag has changed to true, but it is not shown in the UI.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const post = {
    flaggers: [
      {
        refer: false
      },
      {
        refer: false
      }
    ]
  }

  const setToTrue = (flag) => {
    flag.refer = true;
    console.log(post)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {post.flaggers.map((flag) => (
        <div>
          {flag.refer ? <div>true</div> : <div onClick={() => setToTrue(flag)}>false</div>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You cannot use variables created in the project scope as state management; every time the component re-renders, it initializes the value of `post` to the initial value.  You'll need to use a [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to store and manage your state-- note that if your state value is an object, you can't simply mutate it-- you'll need to pass a _new_ object to the state-setting function in order to trigger a new render in React's lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not how `react` you have to setState value to trigger the component to rerender which will cause to UI change try the below code it will work fine as I set a value on `onClick` that causes the component to rerender in short. I would suggest reading the `documentation` before going into the coding and know-how `react` works

[React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)

```
export default function App() {
  const [post, setPost] = React.useState([
    {
      refer: false,
    },
    {
      refer: false,
    },
  ]);

  const setToTrue = (boolFlag, index) => {
    const tempPost = [...post];
    tempPost[index].refer = boolFlag;
    setPost(tempPost);
  };

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {post.map((flag, index) => (
        <div key={`${index}flag`}>
          {flag.refer ? <div onClick={() => setToTrue(false, index)}>true</div> : <div onClick={() => setToTrue(true, index)}>false</div>}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't you need a `useState`?

Comment: fixed! the typo